# Wordpress conditional tag in a page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

i'm new to wordpress and I'm still learning.

I have a search bar in the header of the theme and the client just wants that to be show in the Blog page.

So, i tried conditional tags of wordpress. And I came to this:

```
<?php if (is_page( 'blog' )){ ?>
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php  echo home_url(); ?>/">
    <div id="search-text">
        <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
    <br class="clear">
</form>
<?php }
wp_reset_query();?>
```

I tried with the ID as well.

Plus, I'm making this change directly in the parent theme. How do I use it in the child theme?
In the functions.php or i should upload the searchform.php (that is the file i'm changing) to the root folder of the child theme?

Many thanks.

P.S. I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using css.
What I've done was display none to the Search bar and then display block in the pages I wanted.